# Debatching of large number of XML messages inside MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I am able to debatch the xml messages by loading the xml messages first and then searching for the nodes to be debatched. But it is a poor choice from performance point of view as my solution can be suitable for 10 to 100 messages but for handling 50,000 messages, it is not a suitable choice. So i need some faster approach to do so. Please Help.

**Note:- Please do not suggest any Biztalk based solution.I need simple logic in c# or java.**

Comment: Questions seeking help must include **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/ becouse it does not have message size limition 
also it's support C# and JAVA